# LINQ query to search multiple conditions in a specific order?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a static set of categories, and an incoming list of items that are in various categories. I want to get the first item that matches the best category, and if none is found, get the first item that matches the next-best category, etc. until I get to a default category.

I tried putting my categories in an IEnumerable and doing a `Contains()` on it to see if my incoming items match a category, and stopping on the first match. But I can't control the match order: if the category list is ordered by priority `[best, OK, default]`, the first input item to match *anything* in the category list wins. So if my first input item matches `OK`, and the second input item matches `Best`, then I'll stop before I get the `Best` match.

Right now I run `Where()` over the item list, and if the result is null I run a second `Where()`, etc. I'd like to know if there's a more concise (or more LINQ-idiomatic) way to write this:

```
    public MyVM getVM( IEnumerable<Entities.Foo> foos )
    {
        Entities.Foo foo  = null;
        MyVM         myVM = null;

        if ( entity.IsBar ) 
        {
            foo = foos.Where( f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.BestCat ).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        // no foos are BestCat, look for OkCat
        if ( foo == null ) 
        {
            foo = foos.Where( f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.OkCat ).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        // no foos are OkCat, look for DefaultCat
        if ( foo == null ) 
        {
            foo = foos.Where( f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.DefaultCat ).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if ( foo != null ) 
        {
            myVM = new MyVM() { Name = foo.Name };
        }
        return myVM;
    }

    public enum FooCategories
    {
        DefaultCat,
        SomeCat,
        AnotherCat,
        OkCat,
        BestCat,
        BadCat
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's certainly a more concise way of doing it, in two ways:

- Use the overload of `FirstOrDefault` which takes a predicate
- Use the null-coalescing operator

I'm going to ignore your `IsBar` check for now, because I don't understand how that fits in... but the rest would be:

```
var foo = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.BestCat)
       ?? foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.OkCat)
       ?? foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooCatId == FooCategories.DefaultCat);
```

Another option would be to change your enum order so that you could just find the cat with the best category - either by using `OrderByDescending(f => f.FooCatId)` or by using `MaxBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com/). You'd also then need to check that the resulting cat isn't a bad cat, etc, so it might not be much of a win - but `MaxBy` would at least be more efficient, by only going through the list once.

Comment: D'oh, I forgot about the predicate overload for FirstOrDefault! I'd tried the null-coalescing operator, but my predicates were in a preceding Where clause and it wouldn't work. Don't worry about IsBar -- I missed that when anonymizing my code; it's just the condition for getting the preferred category. In this case, I can't reorder the incoming list, but I can reorder the enums, so I'll play with that, too, but as you say, I don't think there's much gain there by the time I do sanity checks. Thanks for the tips -- very honored to get an answer from you!